# App to send hdmi cec command

Tags: android, shell, hdmi, android-tv

Can I make an app on an Android TV device that sends an HDMI-CEC command?

When you open the app, it should do the command and close.

Is it possible?

Comment: Depends on the details, but probably yes: https://source.android.com/devices/tv/HDMI-CEC.html

Comment: You got any solution?

Comment: @PankajAndroid You need to dig the internet a bit,
use the link above to learn about it.

Comment: @Paz - Can you please add an answer if you have managed to get any HDMI CEC command(s) working?

Comment: any solution yet???

Comment: @A_rmas I added an answer, hope it'll help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google recently introduced a new system service called `HdmiControlService` to handle CEC:

> With the introduction of the Android TV Input Framework (TIF),
>   HDMI-CEC brings together all connected devices and minimizes
>   compatibility issues. Android has created a system service called
>   `HdmiControlService` to alleviate these pain points.
>
> By offering `HdmiControlService` as a part of the Android ecosystem,
>   Android hopes to provide:
>
> - A standard implementation of HDMI-CEC for all manufacturers, which
>     will reduce device incompatibility. Previously, manufacturers had to
>     develop their own implementations of HDMI-CEC or use third-party
>     solutions.
> - A service that is well-tested against numerous HDMI-CEC
>     devices already in the market. Android has been conducting rigorous
>     research on compatibility issues found among the products and
>     collecting useful advice from device implementers experienced in the
>     technology. The CEC service is designed to keep a healthy balance
>     between the standard and modifications to that standard so that it
>     works with the products that people already use.

Learn more about it here: https://source.android.com/devices/tv/hdmi-cec